# jQuery with Javascript check substring of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if there's any way to make this possible. I want to to check if the text value of an element begins with a certain letter.

This is my non working code:

```
if ($('title').text().substring(0, 1) === 'W') {
        $('body').css('background', '#27aae2');
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the  `#element` html ?

Comment: Works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/sh9kh7ty/, `indexOf` would probably be easier ?

Comment: Your code should work.

Comment: Should work. http://jsfiddle.net/rt5n76mq/

Comment: That's odd, it works great in that fiddle. @PedroLobito my element was the title tag

Comment: I updated the example to my actual code, I was just using another example before to cut down on the useless parts but now that I see it's working in the fiddles I would like to see if I made an error in mine.

Comment: `document.title` gets the title as a string. No need to overuse jQuery for that.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy posting your own fiddle might be helpful. I see nothing inherently wrong with what you've posted

Comment: I apologize for wasting everyone's time. I realized that I incorrectly linked the jQuery library in my document. I've flagged the question for a moderator's attention as my code is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
if(yourString.indexOf('A') === 0) {
}
```

Comment: Why search the entire string when you can just test the first letter, like the original code does?

Comment: If you're going to optimize that part, do `yourString[0] == 'a'`

Comment: @arcyqwerty so long as the programmer is aware `yourString[0]` may be `undefined` (use `===`)

Comment: `undefined == 'a'` would be false as expected, same as your implementation (`-1 !== 0`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this work, see code snippet below. Please note it was created based on your original post.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#element').text().substring(0, 1) === 'A') {
    alert('Do something useful')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element">A hello</div>
```